# An 'I'll get right back to you" button

Tags: feature-request

Quite often I ask a question (especially if it is on a project at  work) and I don't have chance to come back to the issue until a few days or even weeks later.

Therefore I thought it would be good to have a button you could click as the asker to show a flag on the question that the asker acknowledges these answers and will get right back to it when they get a minute. This would stop users potentially getting frustrated that they haven't been responded to when there are multiple answers. It would also mean no need to comment 5 times to the various answers.

Comment: Is this really such a big issue? You come back to your answers when *you* want to, not when the persons answering demand you follow up on their posts. There should be no obligation for you here. Of course you can just leave a comment if it has to be. The effort required to implement something like this outweighs any potential benefits.

Comment: Stack Overflow is an asynchronous site. People from all timezones come and go all the time. If users get frustrated because their answers aren't acknowledged right away, they need to work on that.

Comment: But please note that most activity on a question (answers, requests for clarification, et c) happen within the first 10-15 minutes. It's rather important to be there for that activity as, otherwise, questions that are perceived to be lacking in quality or information are likely to be ignored or closed. Stack Overflow seems rather impatient in that regard. =/

Answer (score 1):

Adding this functionality has both advantages and disadvantages.

- Advantages: It will help users to acknowledge that they will get a response.
- Disadvantage: Mostly people will say "I'll get right back to you" and will never accept an answer.

So, I think this functionality will make things worse.